# c# cURL for .net 35

Tags: c#, url

what is my alternative to get file from HTTP in C# with .net 3.5?
I know in 4.5 I can use System.Net.HTTPClient , but what about 3.5? I can't upgrade the framework (have to work on the existing env)

Comment: are you means to download a file or am i wrong?

Comment: yes, WebClient is in .net 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebClient.DownloadFile`   [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s documentation on msdn.